# CSS only select unsorted list in unsorted list ( inner list )

Tags: html, css

Hi I want to select  the inner unsorted list without using the `class=""` argument

I can select the outer list with `"ul li {}"` but how to select only the inner list

```html
    <ul class="listStyleBlueSquare">
        <li>outer List element</li>
        <li>Headline of inner list:
            <ul class="listStyleSquare">
                <li>Inner List element</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: `li li`, `li ul li`, `ul li ul li`...what part are you stuck at? What specific problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these:

```
ul li ul li{}
ul ul li{}
li li{}
```

or with the ">"

```
ul > li > ul > li{}
ul ul > li{}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, how can I access only the first list ? In the moment I access the first list with ul li{} and the styles apply to the second list too

Comment: @Viktor: please, [edit] your question to fully, and clearly, explain your problem. Then you have a better chance of getting a useful answer without having to keep asking clarifying questions.

Answer (score 0):

its

- `ul li ul li{ your-rules: here; }`
- `ul > li > ul >li{ your-rules: here; }`
- `ul ul li { your-rules: here; }`

---

**for 1st child**

```
ul ul li:first-child { 
    your-rules: here; 
}
```

**for nth child**

```
ul ul li:nth-child(n) { 
    your-rules: here; 
}
```

where n belogs to any number.

---

i reccomend you this:

```
ul ul li { your-rules: here; }
```

I recommend giving this a read, it will help you understand the cascade and specificity: [LINK](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/inheritancecascade)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more succinct selector:

```
li > ul {property: value}
```

This grabs an unordered list that's a direct child of a list item.